# Laravel observer pattern for keeping two related models in sync

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.4. I have two related eloquent models:

ImageFile and ClipartImage.

ClipartImage contains a belongsTo relationship as follows:

```
class ClipartImage extends Model
{
    public function image_file()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ImageFile::class, 'image_file_id');
    }

    public function promote()
    {
        $this->image_file->promote();
    }
}
```

On ClipartImage there is a "promote" method which will pass the promote call through to the ImageFile object as it knows how to promote itself.

**The problem I'm running into is if properties change on ImageFile as a result of the method call, there are a couple of properties on the related ClipartImage which may need to be updated as a result. In the ImageFile class I could search the database for any related ClipartImages and update the relevant fields, but this doesn't update the existing ClipartImage instance that I am working with. What's the normal way to solve this sort of dependency between models and keeping the object instances in memory in sync?**

I guess I'm in need of some sort of Observer pattern but in Laravel these things seem to be handled at the static/class level not for individual object instances - ie I could create an observer class that looked for any changes to ImageFile models, but that isn't going to help me refresh or update my existing ClipartImage object.

---

**Edit:** I've used a single "promote" method to illustrate, but there's a bunch of interaction between ClipartImage and the ImageFile class and it's not obvious from the point of view of ClipartImage when it may need to refresh or update itself. Ideally ImageFile would inform it when key fields have changed so it can respond accordingly.

Comment: Too much explanation. Please update and add only the PROBLEM and WANT TO ACCOMPLISH.

Comment: What so people can then complain there's not enough context information or no details of what i've considered already? I'll put the problem in bold, how about that.

Comment: try calling `fresh` method on the instance.